# Why does the screen show vertical lines?

Tags: broken-screen

I have a small tablet, but my sibling dropped it. Whenever it is turned on, the screen is just covered in vertical, multicolored lines.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of help do you expect from us?

Comment: Any tips that could possibly make it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably broken inside. I'd suggest you send it to a service center for checking.